# Where to put Administrative Features

Tags: architecture

Right now we have our administrative features located at www.mysite.com/admin.  It is locked down by UN/PW but it still seems like an insecure place to have it.  Is there a better place to put it?  Perhaps at another domain?

Comment: If you know the IP range of your admin users (e.g. from within a certain office, for example) you can lock it down by that additionally.

Comment: A secure system doesn't become less secure by making it easy to find. An insecure system doesn't become more secure by making it hard to find. See [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: Note that Nikolai's idea is real security. "Hard to find" is insecure. "Literally impossible to find" is secure. But still, guessing a hostname is in the same order of complexity as guessing a username - and usernames are considered good security.

Comment: @Nikolai, I would classify that under "false sense of security".  This presumes lack of physical access to the machine which I think is unreliable.

Comment: @cdkMoose: Security has to be measured against a precisely defined threat.  A malicious actor on the internet, with or without knowledge of the systems to be protected, is one kind of threat.  A malicious actor in the server room is another kind of threat.  It may be perfectly sensible to protect against one but not the other.

Comment: @kevincline, you are right to point out that the security measures necessary are dictated by the environment.  My point was just that depending on the operational profile, those IPs may not be all that definitive.  Many app administrators don't work in the server room, so their IPs are from a larger pool.  Depends how much someone would want to hack your system, but if I was a visitor to the company and get an IP for my SmartPhone/mobile device, it could look like an internal address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ensure that the area of a website is secure by having:

- long passwords,
- or a good security audit with the maximum number of failed login attempts before lock,
- or a two-step verification,
- or anything else which actually increases the security level,

no by:

- moving the area somewhere else,
- never documenting it, hoping that nobody will find it,
- or any other "it's hidden, so it's secure" technique.